# How to enable Google analytics while site is in maintenance mode?

Tags: 7, google-analytics, maintenance-mode

I want to know how many users visit my site that is currently in maintenance mode. I have installed the google analytics module, but it doesn't add google tracking codes to the maintenance page, so google analytics says "Tracking not installed".

How do I enable it while site is in maintenance mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it manually unfortunately, the normal page building handler isn't called for the maintenance page so the analytics module never actually builds up the necessary javascript.

You can follow the instructions [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!maintenance-page.tpl.php/7) to set up a custom maintenance page template, from there you'll just need to add the tracking code manually to the bottom of the site. It should start working instantly.